# Is it possible to exclude specified GET parameters in apache access logs?

Tags: regex, apache, logging

I need to exclude some sensitive details in my apache log, but I want to keep the log and the uri's in it. Is it possible to achieve following in my access log:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [27/Feb/2012:13:18:12 +0100] "GET /api.php?param=secret HTTP/1.1" 200 7600 "http://localhost/api.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/535.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/17.0.963.56 Safari/535.11"
```

I want to replace "secret" with "[FILTERED]" like this:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [27/Feb/2012:13:18:12 +0100] "GET /api.php?param=[FILTERED] HTTP/1.1" 200 7600 "http://localhost/api.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/535.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/17.0.963.56 Safari/535.11"
```

I know I probably should have used POST to send this variable, but the damage is already done. I've looked at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/logs.html and LogFormat, but could not find any possibilities to use regular expression or similar. Any suggestions?

**[edit]**

Do NOT send sensitive variables as GET parameters if you have the possibility to choose.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I've found one way to solve the problem. If I pipe the log output to `sed`, I can perform a regex replace on the output before I append it to the log file.

**Example 1**

```
CustomLog "|/bin/sed -E s/'param=[^& \t\n]*'/'param=\[FILTERED\]'/g >> /your/path/access.log" combined
```

**Example 2**

It's also possible to exclude several parameters:

`exclude.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
while read x ; do
    result=$x
    for ARG in "$@"
    do
        cleanArg=`echo $ARG | sed -E 's|([^0-9a-zA-Z_])|\\\\\1|g'`
        result=`echo $result | sed -E s/$cleanArg'=[^& \t\n]*'/$cleanArg'=\[FILTERED\]'/g`
    done
    echo $result
done
```

Move the script above to the folder /opt/scripts/ or somewhere else, give the script execute rights (`chmod +x exclude.sh`) and modify your apache config like this:

```
CustomLog "|/opt/scripts/exclude.sh param param1 param2 >> /your/path/access.log" combined
```

**Documentation**

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/logs.html#piped

http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html

Comment: When I try the same thing, I get an error saying "/bin/sed: can't read >>: No such file or directory". Did you see this too?

Comment: did you change the path to a existing file? '/your/path/access.log'

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work for me. It just doesn't log anything when using this script...

Comment: Same issue here, fixed by using "|$/bin/sed .." instead of "|/bin/sed". As the documentation states, this executes the command inside a shell. Note that this was the default behavior of "|" in the past, but that was changed at some point.
Nevertheless, this doesn't solve all the problems of the line for me, as the regular expressions tends to not be correctly passed to sed... I'm using apache 2.4.39.

Comment: we use 'CustomLog "|/usr/sbin/cronolog -z EST -H /opt/cc/logs/http/my-access_current /opt/cc/logs/http/my-access.%Y-%m-%d-00_00_00.log" common  env=!dontlog'     to generate access logs. Regardless before or after cronolog I put sed command to regex the to-skip parameter, it does not work (stop logging). Wondering if anyone has example of combining sed with cronolog

Answer (score 2):

If you want to exclude several parameters, but don't want to use a script, you can use groups like that :

```
CustomLog "|$/bin/sed -E s/'(email|password)=[^& \t\n]*'/'\\\\\1=\[FILTERED\]'/g >> /var/log/apache2/${APACHE_LOG_FILENAME}.access.log" combined
```