# is it possible to save the request URL which has been replaced by regular expressions into the apache access.log?

Tags: java, apache

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to exclude specified GET parameters in apache access logs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9467405/is-it-possible-to-exclude-specified-get-parameters-in-apache-access-logs)

There has a security hole hidden in apache's log:

such as if you input a URL about **http://localhost/meeting/import.php?cmd=admin&password=pass&userName=hsh&meetingID=123** into the browser,then the access.log will complete record it, so this is a security question because it recording the security parameter:**cmd=admin&password=pass&userName=hsh&meetingID=123**.

Now,I want to control my log printing that make the parameter replaced with @ symbol, if I execute a url which not including security parameter such as **http://localhost/meeting/op.do**, access.log must record it, **but** if I input a url which incuding security parameter such as **http://localhost/meeting/import.php>?cmd=admin&password=pass&userName=hsh&meetingID=123** ,then the regular expression replacement must work and it will sove:
**http://localhost/meeting/import.php?cmd=@@&password=@@&userName=@@&meetingID=@@** into logs,What should I go to achieve?
remind:My develop environment is W7.thanks!

Comment: If your GET params contain sensitive information, your web application is designed faulty. In this case, log file contents should be your least concern! Anyway, see [Is it possible to exclude specified GET parameters in apache access logs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9467405) for a solution.

Comment: Thanks for your response,and i am extremely agree with you opinion about my faulty APP design,but I want to know if there is a solution for this case or not.