# CustomLog fails when piped to sed

Tags: apache, sed, httpd.conf

I am trying to use a piped CustomLog to filter my logs:

**httpd.conf**:

```
CustomLog "|/bin/sed -r s/pass/REDACTED/g >> /workplace/tmp/access.log" common
```

However, when I make a request to Apache, I get an error saying

```
/bin/sed: can't read >>: No such file or directory
```

What am I doing wrong here? (It seems [others have been able to use piped CustomLog like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9467405/is-it-possible-to-exclude-specified-get-parameters-in-apache-access-logs))

Comment: What does ls /workplace/tmp/access.log return?

Comment: It shows the file. I made sure that everyone has write permissions: -rw-rw-rw-

Answer (score 4):

I just solved this and thought I should put an update here even though this thread is old.

First, the poster above who suggested that the input file was missing is not correct. There is no input file. Apache is sending the logging messages to sed through a pipe, not through a file.

The trick here is to tell apache to launch a shell for the sed command. Without launching a shell, the ">>" has no special meaning and is treated like a filename. To tell apache to launch a shell for the sed, you append a "$" after the pipe symbol like this:

```
CustomLog "|$/bin/sed s/'creditCardPAN=[^ ]*'/'creditCardPAN=REDACTED'/ >>logs/ssl_access_log" PaymentLogFormat
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the input file. Should be :

```
sed -r s/pass/REDACTED/g myInputFile.txt >> /workplace/tmp/access.log
```

Answer (score 0):

for our PCI-DSS compliance, I remove every 16 digit sequence from log before writing it with this customlog

```
CustomLog '|$/usr/bin/sed -r \"s:\([345][0-9]{5}\)\([0-9]{6}\)\([0-9]{4}\):\\\1******\\\3:g\" >> logs/access_log' common
```

*PS: I don't check luhn checksum*

**checks**

`curl https://<instance>/A3000001111112222B` -> `GET /A300000******2222B`

`curl https://<instance>/A32345612345612343234561234561234B` -> `GET /A323456******1234323456******1234`