# Is there a way to filter out some requests from php-fpm access logs?

Tags: php, logging, fpm

I am setting up a server with nginx and php-fpm and am looking for a way to prevent some requests from being logged in the fpm access log. 
I have set up fpm access logs using the access.log directive in fpm.conf.

Something like the solution provided for apache in [Is it possible to exclude specified GET parameters in apache access logs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9467405/is-it-possible-to-exclude-specified-get-parameters-in-apache-access-logs)

Comment: When asking a question, people will be better able to provide help if you provide code that they can easily understand and use to reproduce the problem. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @SimónRamírezAmaya, but I am not sure there is any code which will help this question.